# Linq Take is being ignored in SQL statement if a group join is included

Tags: linq-to-sql, mariadb

Essentially, the generated SQL from Linq appears to be ignoring the "Take" command when we include a group join of the following Invoices table.

```
                        var queryCommand = from m in _context.CustomerInfo
                                       join sq in customerAnalysisGroupQuery on m.CustomerInfoId equals sq.customerAnalysisGroupQueryCustomerInfoId
                                       join igq in _context.Invoices on m.CustomerInfoId equals igq .invoicesGroupQueryCustomerInfoId into igq2
                                       from igq in igq2.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                       select new TableModelForServerPagination()
                                       {
                                           reportInfo = sq,
                                           customerInfo = m,
                                           invoicesInfo = igq 
                                       };


                                       var queryList = queryCommand.Take(50).ToList();
```

The invoices table may contain multiple invoices for each customer. The analysis query generates one analysis for each customer.

The generated SQL code results in
one very long sql query which ends incorrectly with
Order by m.CustomerInfoId

If we ommit the invoices table, the generated code results in
one very long sql query which ends correctly with
LIMIT 50

Taking the wrongly generated SQL query and adding "LIMIT 50" to it produces the same results as the correctly generated SQL query.

We are using MariaDB and entity .net core 3.1. Might anyone have an insight as to what happened here?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out we were using a IEnumerable to store invoicesInfo. Once that's removed, it generates the query correctly with the Limit 50.